# TLS decryption using Wireshark: Where to find RSA key?

Tags: rsa, wireshark, tls1.2

I am capturing network packets using wireshark and I need to decrypt TLS traffic. There is a procedure to be followed as mentioned on many websites [check here](https://support.f5.com/csp/article/K19310681).
There is a step mentioned to add RSA key while editing preferences for TLS however I am not able to find the key itself. Where can I find this key?

Comment: See if this helps: https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9834/69/how-can-i-find-the-private-key-for-my-ssl-certificate/

Comment: The RSA key can only be found of the web server (if it still uses RSA at all). The linked web page is a bit outdated. On modern TLS ciphers instead the pre-master secret key log is used als the old RSA based decryption version does no longer work. This pre-master key log file can be generated by a modified client or server. https://www.comparitech.com/net-admin/decrypt-ssl-with-wireshark/

Comment: @Robert I've tried using pre-master key log file procedure but my keys are not getting saved in the file I specified in environment variable. I've tried restarting my browser many times but no luck

Comment: If you simply want to capture web-browser content a HTTPS intercepting proxy like Fiddler Classic or Mitmproxy would by my preferred choice. Wireshark is a bit complicated for that.

Comment: Aren't these softwares unsafe to use?